# Move Models Between R Projects

Tags: r

I am currently working on a project that requires creating several very complicated models in R. The first took upwards of ten hours to run on my maxed out 2016 MacBook Pro, and there are 6 more that are increasingly complicated.

Is there a way to run each model in seperate R projects on seperate machines and then import the finished models into a single project when they are finished? I have access to enough computers to run each model on its own computer overnight, but I’m not sure if that would accomplish what I need it to.

Comment: Yes, see `help("readRDS")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To move an object (any object, not just a very complicated model) between R sessions (the term Project is usually, at least in R Studio, used in a different context) use `saveRDS()` and then `readRDS()`

eg. let `foo` be a well trained model:

```
saveRDS(foo, "foo.rds")
```

copy / paste the foo.rds file to a different machine

```
foo2 <- readRDS("foo.rds")
```

and voila! you have just saved / read a file from the disk